# Footer does not sit at the bottom of the page, content div height 0

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm going crazy with this:

The content div height is 0, so the footer is not at the bottom of the page. It ends up sitting right below the header div.

I can't for the life of me figure this out. I know that if the img's were floated the parent div wouldnt get the height of the child elements...wondering if that is the only way to go or if there is a better way to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated!!! TIA

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 0;

  function slideshow() {
    if (i == 0) {
      $("#splash1").fadeIn(5000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#splash2").fadeIn(5000);
          $("#splash1").fadeOut(5000);
        }, 2000);
        i++;
        slideshow();
      });
    } else if (i == 1) {
      $("#splash2").fadeIn(5000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#splash3").fadeIn(5000);
          $("#splash2").fadeOut(5000);
        }, 2000);
        i++;
        slideshow();
      });
    } else if (i == 2) {
      $("#splash3").fadeIn(5000, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#splash1").fadeIn(5000);
          $("#splash3").fadeOut(5000);
        }, 2000);
        i = 0;
        slideshow();
      });

    }
  }

  slideshow();

});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  min-width: 1080px;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="content">
    <img id="splash1" src="assets/img/background_splash1.jpg" style='width:100%;height:auto; position: absolute;' />
    <img id="splash2" src="assets/img/background_splash2.jpg" style='width:100%;height:auto; display:none; position: absolute;' />
    <img id="splash3" src="assets/img/background_splash3.jpg" style='width:100%;height:auto; display:none; position: absolute;' />
  </div>

  <div id="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Remove `position: relative;` from the `#wrapper`, or set it to `initial`

Comment: @SubjectDelta that moved the footer down but not all the way....content height is still 0

Comment: Would you consider flexbox for your layout instead of positioning?

Comment: I added display:flex; flex-wrap:row; to the wrapper div and the content height is still 0....

Comment: Images have `position: absolute;`, the container acts as it is empty

Comment: how do I fix that? If I dont have absolute the images snap in from below....

Comment: try to remove position absolute to the img, and set float: left, remeber to add a clearfix the content div.